# Wordpress WP_DEBUG=true but no error is shown

Tags: php, wordpress

I’ve turn on WP_DEBUG in wp-config.php:

```
    define('WP_DEBUG', true);
    define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
    define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
    @ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

I want to get a warn in cases like this:

```
  $qry=new WP_Query([
             'posttye'  => 'post',
             'category_name' => 'featured'
         ]);
        ?>

               <?php if (have_posts()):?>
                  <?php while($qry->have_posts()):$qry->the_post();?>
                      <?php  echo  $qry->current_post();?>
                  <?php endwhile;?>
              <?php endif;?>
```

the problem is there : **$qry->current_post()**,current_post is not method is just a field,correct
is : **$qry->current_post**

in case of incorrect syntax it is echo empty string but I want a warning/error

I’ve tested also a php script

```
class myClass{
 var $field1="value 1";
  function Method1(){
      echo("field1 is :".$this->field1()); 
     // correct is  echo("field1 is :".$this->field1); 
  }

 }

$obj=new myClass();
$obj->Method1();
```

and I got:
**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method myClass::field1() in index.php on line 6
( ! ) Error: Call to undefined method myClass::field1() in index.php on line 6**

how to have this in WP too
thanks!

Comment: try define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
@ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Hi,not working,only fatal errors are shown/written in debug.log,like $qry->current_post(') thanks